# Jmeter saving the results of recording

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to save results of recording as well?  I have to record it several times if I forget not to close the window, which I always do.

Answer (score 0):

The recorded activity will automatically save under your **Test Plan**.You will find all the recorded samples under the **"Recording Controller"**After you stop recording you will see the recorded script in JMeter with all your activity in the browser.It will automatically update under **Thread Group**.This script will contain all your page requests during browsing activity.

> **Here is the step by step process of recording browsers action.**

**Step1:** Open **Firefox** browser and from **Network Connection** settings configure the **proxy server** as **HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1, Port: 8888**

[image]

**Step2:** Run your **Jmeter.bat** file and open **Templates** under File dropdown list and click **"Create"**.

[image]

**Step3:** Expand Work Bench and select **"HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder"**. And click **"Start"** at the bottom of the page.You will have two pop up to Allow **Firewall** and **Temporary Root CA Certification Installation**.Allow all those and now go to your browser and do your browser activity.When it's done **"Stop"** the **HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder**.

**Step4:** After this you will get the recorded script in JMeter with all your activity in the browser.It will automatically update under **Thread Group**.This script will contain all your page requests during browsing activity. Sample script after recording is shown below.

[image]

So after finishing your recording you will get the **Recorded Script** as a **.jmx** file after saving.

You would also like to go through the Apache documentation of [HTTP(s) Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for further details.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation.  However, what I am asking is if I close this window, the entire recording results are gone.  I want to retain that to see my variables.  And also I do not have to record them again if i have to see them

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has an inbuilt functionality to save the recording. Maybe you can follow the content that is available on this page.
http://www.codetut.com/2017/10/saving-jmeter-recording.html

Comment: From next time onwards, if you are going to provide a link as an answer; post some relevant codes/steps to back it up as links may die!